# Is this a stack?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles

A continuous map $f:X\to Y$ and a vector bundle $E\to X$ seem to give rise to a presheaf of groupoids on $Y$ along the following lines. For an open $U\subseteq Y$, each section of $f$ over $U$ (i. e. a map $s:U\to X$ with $fs=$ inclusion) produces a vector bundle $s^*E$ on $U$ and for another section $t:U\to X$, a homotopy class $H$ of homotopies between $s$ and $t$ that induce trivial homotopy between $fs$ and $ft$ gives rise to a bundle isomorphism between $s^*E$ and $t^*E$.

Question 0: can this be finalized to indeed yield a presheaf of groupoids?

Question 1 (in case the answer to the previous one is "yes"): is this a stack? Are there some natural restrictions on $f$ and $E$ (like $f$ being some kind of fibration, etc.) which ensure that one gets a stack? Or maybe some modifications of the construction? For example, instead of $fs = $ inclusion one might add to the structure a homotopy between $fs$ and inclusion, and some coherence requirement; or, instead of demanding that $H$ induces a trivial homotopy, one might make part of the structure a choice of a homotopy between $fH:fs\sim ft$ and the trivial homotopy $fs = $ inclusion $ = ft$.

Question 2: is this an instance of some known construction?

Maybe I should add that I am actually interested in a very particular case, when $f$ is a fibration of smooth manifolds, with fibres all smooth, and $E$ is the tangent-along-the fibres bundle.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Spaces? Schemes? If spaces this is naturally a presheaf of ∞-groupoids, not of groupoids. Of course you can truncate, but you'll probably lose descent properties

Comment: @DenisNardin Spaces, as good as you want - say, finite CW-complexes.

Comment: Can you please clarify which category are you associating to an open subset $U$ of $Y$?.. sorry if it is already stated clearly but I am not able to see it.. Is it the category of vector bundles over $U$ obtained as pullbacks of sections $s:U\rightarrow X$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You see it right - I don't know, this is part of the question 0 :D But at least whatever it can be it certainly can only contain vector bundles of the same rank as $E$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე same rank? what is the first reason for imposing that condition?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik We only have $E$ at hand, any of its pullbacks anywhere wil have the same rank, no way to get any other, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that was a stupid comment :D May be I was half sleeping :D You are absolutely correct...